# I'm not getting this meaning of 'que' here

Tags: que

This is from Valery's La Jeune Parque

> Je n’attendais pas moins de mes riches déserts
> Qu’un tel enfantement de fureur et de tresse

This was translated as:

> I was expecting from my fertile deserts
> Some writhing birth like this, some plait of fury:

I get that `ne ... que` means `only`, but here 'ne' seems to be joined to 'pas', unless 'pas' is joined to 'moins' meaning 'a lot' and 'ne' is joined to 'que' in which case a literal translation would be:

I expected not a few from my fertile deserts, [rather] only such births of fury and tresses.

Help me out here, because I can't figure out what 'que' is doing in that sentence.

Comment: Potentially interesting: [Que la lumière soit. Et la lumière fut.](https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Et_la_lumi%C3%A8re_fut#:~:text=Cette%20phrase%20est%20une%20traduction,%2C%20et%20la%20lumi%C3%A8re%20fut%20%C2%BB.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The *que* attaches to the comparative *moins*.

*Moins que* = less than, so *pas moins que* = no less than.

And this *pas*, incorporated in such a construction, is still able to function as the negative particle.

« Je n'attendais pas moins qu'un tel enfantement », then, is

> I expected no less than a creation such as this

Comment: thanks, I appreciate that.